# Kirchhoff's voltage and current law

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws

Why is that Kirchhoff's voltage and current law always give answer? I mean if we apply node method at the end we can write the equations in form of matrix. The matrix could be singular, but it always gives an answer; why is that?

Answer (score 2):

> Why is that Kirchhoff's voltage and current law always give answer?

They don't *always* give answer.  For example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f03neV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

KVL applied to the above gives:

$$1V = 2V$$

which is a contradiction.

Another example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFZwZx.png)</sup>

KCL applied to the above gives:

$$1A = -2A$$

which is a contradiction.

Another example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQnrnH.png)</sup>

KCL applied to the above gives

$$\frac{V}{1 \Omega} =  \frac{V}{1 \Omega}$$

so the voltage and current are undetermined.

The fact is, it is possible to draw an ideal circuit schematic that is inconsistent or has undetermined voltages or currents.

Furthermore, node voltage analysis relies on KCL while mesh current analysis relies on KVL so I don't quite understand the 2nd part of your question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to realize that you are applying physical/mathematical rules to an electric circuit that is realizable, i.e. it could be built using real resistors, capacitors, inductors, etc. Thus the circuit's currents and voltages must exist.  Thus any method that uses the physical models of these components to calculate these currents and voltages must yield a physically realizable answer.  The reverse, however, is not necessarily true, i.e. you can create mathematical models of circuit elements that are not physically realizable.

Comment: A circuit schematic is nothing more than a graphical representation of differential equations.

Answer (score -1):

Originally these were experimental laws, however they can be developed from Maxwell's equations.

[Here someone already showed the steps](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/102458/how-can-kvl-kcl-be-derived-from-maxwell-equations).